# How to make choosing group in admin.py mandatory?

Tags: django, django-admin

In admin.py, I am adding `groups` as fieldset to one of my model.

```
   fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )
```

The issue I have is that I do not know how to make choosing them mandatory - user can be in each or both of them, but cannot be blank. How can I force it, to ensure that user added will be in a group?

Comment: have you implemented a custom user model ?

Comment: Yes, to ensure that if person is registered, then you need first/last name and email as well

Comment: see if this works, add this in your user model
https://www.codepile.net/pile/nMK4pOWa